# Sharepoint web part form validation blocks updating web part settings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have written a web part in C# for Sharepoint 2007 which has a single field which is validated as a required field using `RequiredFieldValidator()`.  The web part also has some configuration fields (ones you edit by clicking on Modify Shared Web Part).

When I make changes to these fields and try to apply them, the validation of the user field kicks in and prevents the update, even though I am not submitting the form.  I am only trying to submit the settings.  The web part may be used in a few places on our farm, so site collection administrators need to be able to change the settings - at the moment it is not friendly enough for these users to do so.

Here is where I validate the user field:

```
// Validate form field - required field, and max length is 100 characters.
InputFormRequiredFieldValidator messageRequiredValidator = new InputFormRequiredFieldValidator();
messageRequiredValidator.ControlToValidate = txtMessage.ID;
messageRequiredValidator.ErrorMessage = "You must write a message to send!";
messageRequiredValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
messageRequiredValidator.Text = "<img src=\"/_layouts/images/CNSCA16.gif\"/> You must write a message to send.";
tc.Controls.Add(messageRequiredValidator);
```

Here is where I define one of the configuration fields:

```
private string recipientEmailAddress = "sender@domain.tld";
    [WebBrowsable(true),
    Personalizable(true),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared),
    WebDescription("Email address the form should be sent to"),
    WebDisplayName("Recipient Email Address"),
    SPWebCategoryName("Email Settings")]
    public string RecipientEmailAddress
    {
        get { return recipientEmailAddress; }
        set { recipientEmailAddress = value; }
    }
```

This is the first web part I have written, so there may be some subtleties I am missing in how to do admin configuration and validation of user submitted fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - I've found the key to this.  You can add a [validationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) property to each validator, and to the button that causes the validation.  So I changed my code to include:

```
messageRequiredValidator.validationGroup = "UserInput";
```

and a similar property to my submit button.  Now when I click on Ok in the ToolPane, it doesn't validate the UserInput validation group.  That only happens when I click on my Submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically disable validations on OK, Cancel buttons in ApplyChanges method:

```
ToolPane pane = Zone as ToolPane;
if (pane != null)
    pane.Cancel.CausesValidation = false;
```

OR you can also check if editor pane is open and disable validation in webpart :

WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);

```
if (wpm.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.EditDisplayMode)
 {
      //Page is in edit mode
 }
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to validate the editor pane fields when setting up the web part - does this disable that as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [SharePoint validation control](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/sharepoint-validation-controls/).

Comment: I've changed the code to use those different validator controls (and updated question), but the same issue arises - validation of the public fields kicks in when changing the web part settings fields.